# how to reduce image size or quality to specific size when upload

Tags: php, mysql

in a PHP query form i'm trying to set limit for the image size whenever user upload any size of image  automatically reduces to a specific size.
i don't have any idea, so give me some suggestion to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link 
https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-reduce-image-file-size-while-uploading-using-php-code/

below example for reducing the image size while uploading in PHP.

```
    <?php
    $name = ''; $type = ''; $size = ''; $error = '';
    function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {

        $info = getimagesize($source_url);

            if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

            imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
        return $destination_url;
    }

    if ($_POST) {

            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                    $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
            } 
            else if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || 
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || 
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || 
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) {

                    $url = 'destination .jpg';

                    $filename = compress_image($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $url, 80);
                    $buffer = file_get_contents($url);

                    /* Force download dialog... */
                    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
                    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                    header("Content-Type: application/download");

            /* Don't allow caching... */
                    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

                    /* Set data type, size and filename */
                    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer));
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$url");

                    /* Send our file... */
                    echo $buffer;
            }else {
                    $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png";
            }
    }
?>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Php code compress the image</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="message">
                        <?php
                            if($_POST){
                                if ($error) {
                                    ?>
                                    <label class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></label>
                        <?php
                                    }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
        <fieldset class="well">
                        <legend>Upload Image:</legend>                
            <form action="" name="myform" id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <ul>
                            <li>
                        <label>Upload:</label>
                                            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn-success"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```